# Howto prevent a CFrameWnd from being mouse moved

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an application that displays a CFrameWnd that is displayed on top of the main window. I need the window to be non-movable and non-resizable when the user selects a certain mode for the window.
My CFrameWnd is created with the styles `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_POPUP`

I have come across a solution using an overload of CWndOnNcHitTest to rewrite
`HTLEFT,HTRIGHT,HTTOP,HTTOPLEFT,HTTOPRIGHT,HTBOTTOM,HTBOTTOMLEFT,HTBOTTOMRIGHT,HTSIZE,HTCAPTION`to `HTBORDER`to prevent the framework to recognize the areas responsible for sizing / moving.
This method works well for resizing in my case, but moving the window is still possible, although the hittest override works correctly (verified with traces).

Is there anything wrong in my approach, or could there be something interfering with this solution and if so, do you have any tips on where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make OnNcHitTest() work, don't return HTCAPTION.

Still, there's more than one way to move/size a window, you also have to worry about the system menu (type Alt+Space).  Write a message handler for WM_MOVING and WM_SIZING and override the RECT so the window stays put.

Comment: Thanks! Adding an override of OnMoving and setting the target Rect to the current window did the trick. The guid I had previously found did not mention the WM_MOVING message.